# How do i secure a long disk operation (writing)?

Tags: android

If i have to write a lot of bytes to 'disk' how do i make sure, that this operation is not interrupted or the user/system starts other file operations that could cause trouble ?

I am just worried, that when my ASyncTask writes to disk for about 30 seconds, that other processes in the foreground may work on the disk and my stuff gets corrupted. I have no idea how android manages its disk accesses.

Or is it no problem at all ? I just need to know, that my data is written to disk correctly, no matter how long it takes.

I know that the SQLite database i can start exclusive transfers and stuff, but i doubt i can lock the disk for my app only, that would be malware heaven.

Comment: The OS makes sure your app (Or any app for that matter) gets it's fair share of time accessing the disk. Don't worry

Comment: It deserves a test but I think that even switching the device off would not interrupt this operation. The only problem could be the battery that finishes. (Should you test that let us know, this would be interesting for everybody.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android is running on a mature Linux Kernel. At any given time, there are dozens of 'disk' operations active. Your app is but a small part of the big game. No worries, write as long as you want -- as long as you close your file before the system shuts down, your app crashes, or the user kills it, your file operation will complete. Even in any of the above cases, the storage should not be corrupted. Proper system shutdowns and process terminations should close all open resources. Even if your system suddenly loses power, thanks to the ext4 file system, disk corruption should be rare.